# "О" в слове "метро"

Tags: морфемика

Чем является "О" в слове "Метро"?

Answer (score 3):

К. И. Чуковский, «Эгофутуристы», 1922 год [НКРЯ]:

> Ведь когда `автомобиль` мы называем `авто`, а `метрополитен` — `метро`, когда вместо утомительных слов:
> конституционно-демократическая партия, мы двусложно говорим к.-д., а вместо `Южное-Русское Общество Торговли Аптекарскими Товарами` говорим инициально `Юротат`, здесь именно различные методы такого сгущения, убыстрения речи, и заслуга эгофутуристов именно в том, что они первые приобщили к поэзии подобные городские речения, доселе презираемые как вульгарность.

Из [викисловаря](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE):

> Слово происходит от французского `métro` «метро», сокращение от `métropolitain` «столичный, городской», от существительного `métropole` «метрополия, центр»... " из `μήτηρ` (`mḗtēr`) «мать», от протогреческого `*mā́tēr"` и "из `πόλις` «город, государство» (восходит к праиндоевр. `*p(o)lH`- «огороженное место»)".

Вывод:

"О" в "обрусевшем" слове "метро", это последняя буква неизменяемой части слова, то есть - корня.